# load the data from file using multi threading

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to load the data into PostgreSQL table using java program.
In the java program I want to use multi threading and I use the COPY command API

```
CopyManager copyManager = ((PGConnection)conn).getCopyAPI();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
copyManager.copyIn("COPY "+tblname+ " FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' ", fileReader);
```

I have divided the file into 'n' parts and then each thread load that part into PostgreSQL table.

**Example:**
file:test.csv
Thread=3

then `test1.csv,test2.csv,test3.csv` is created. and each thread execute each file.
it works correctly.

Now I want to check the data loading performance using multi threading of single file(not divide the file into n no of file)

**Example:**

file: test.csv(contain 30000 records)
thread =3(1st thread execute the 1st 10000 rows,
 2nd thread execute the 1000120000 and 3rd thread execute the 20001-30000);

three thread divide the content of file and load the data into Postgres using COPY.

Is it possible to divide the records of file and load into Postgres using java multithreading?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's possible, it would be stupid. What is it with all these posts about trying to make file reading multithreaded?

Comment: I can't see any valid reason either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing something to a storage will prevent all other threads from writing to the same. You cannot simply make everything multithreaded.

In this case all other parts Need to wait for the previous one to finish.